# How to specify text qualifier in Teradata? Bug or unvoiced restriction?

Tags: java, teradata

I tried using [Teradata fastload](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samp/T20208JD.java.txt)

Here is [the sample file that they provide on the official website](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/samples.jar)

```
L_INDEX,L_TIMESTAMP,L_TEXT
1,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,some text
2,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,
3,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,more text
4,,text
5,,
```

It runs perfect with the above file

---

Then I modified ONLY the first row . So that   `some text` became `"some, text"` . **The following is a perfectly legit `csv`**

```
L_INDEX,L_TIMESTAMP,L_TEXT
1,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,"some, text"      // this row was slightly modified
2,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,
3,2010-08-11 13:19:05.1,more text
4,,text
5,,
```

However I got an error saying that `the first column contains 4 values but only 3 values were expected`

---

As far as **I understand I must  specify text qualifier** `"` . How can I do this ?

I read [documentation](http://developer.teradata.com/doc/connectivity/jdbc/reference/current/jdbcug_chapter_2.html#BABFGFAF) but nothing is mentioned about this .

Comment: You are right . This fastload i suseless unless you have a very simple csv file . use batches

Answer (score 2):

According to the FastLoad Utility documentation pertaining to the selection of a delimiter for use with the `SET RECORD` command and a `VARTEXT` layout:

> Any character sequence that appears in the data cannot be used as a
>   delimiter. No control character other than a tab character can be used
>   in a delimiter.

This would likely extend to the use of the FastLoad API mechanism leveraged within the Teradata JDBC driver.

**EDIT**

FastLoad has been around for 15+ years and does what it was intended to well -- load lots of data fast. Your other options would be to create a fixed length record where you do not have to rely on a delimiter or create an INMOD to parse the file as it is streamed into FastLoad.

Other alternatives include MultiLoad, Teradata Parallel Transport, TPUMP, or a proper ETL tool to load your data. Each have their own advantages and disadvantages that have to be considered with the format of the data which is being supplied to the environment.

Comment: +1 So, simply speaking `FastLoad is useless UNLESS the csv is ridiculously simple which almost never is the case`